# Can not make the mocked singleton's method behave differently in different test cases

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, singleton, powermockito

The unit test of a class is involved with a static method in a another class, say `HelperClass`. `HelperClass` has a singleton member. I used `Junit` for the unit tests and `Powermockito` to mock the singleton member. But I found that the behavior of the method of the singleton member can only be specified once.

```
//the class to be tested
class Activity {
    public void enact() {
        //some logic
        String str = HelperClass.doSomething();
        //some other logic
    }
}

class HelperClass {
    private static final singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
    public static String doSomething() {
       //some logic
       AnObject obj;
       try {
           obj = singleton.doSomething();
       } catch (Exception1 e) {
           //Some other logic
           throw new Exception2("Some message" + e.getMessage(), e);
       }

       String val = obj.doSomething();
       return val;
    }
}

class Singleton {
    private Singleton instance = null;
    private void Singleton() { /*some logic*/ }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public String doSomething() throws Exception1 {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

My uint test goes like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Singleton.class)
class ActivityTest {
     //some logic
     private Activity activity;

     @Before
     public void setup() {
         //some logic
         PowerMockito.mockStatic(Singleton.class);
         activity = new Activity();
     }

     @Test(expected = Exception2.class)
     void test1() {
        Singleton mockSingleton = mock(Singleton.class);
        when(mockSingleton.doSomething()).thenThrow(new Exception1("Test Exception1"));
        PowerMockito.when(Singleton.getInstance()).thenReturn(mockSingleton);

        activity.enact();
     }

     @Test
     void test2() {
        Singleton mockSingleton = mock(Singleton.class);
        when(mockSingleton.doSomething()).thenReturn("");
        PowerMockito.when(Singleton.getInstance()).thenReturn(mockSingleton);

        activity.enact();
     }
}
```

But it does not work. Although I specify different behaviors of the `doSomething()` of the `mockSingleton`, the `mockSingleton` still throws the `Exception2` in `test2` as it does in `test1`. It seems that the behavior can only be specified once. Can somebody tell me how I can let the `doSomething()` here have different behaviors?

Comment: Mockito you run with goes for class, not for ibstance, and static mockito could preserve state for class tests. Is there annotation run with on method level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Signleton.getInstance` only once - when `HelperClass` is initialized. This way you always use the mock from your first test. To solve this, you can call `getInstance` every time you need an instance of `Singleton`.

Thus, the code for `HelperClass` would be:

```
class HelperClass {
    public static String doSomething() {
       //some logic
       AnObject obj;
       try {
           obj = Singleton.getInstance().doSomething();
       } catch (Exception1 e) {
           //Some other logic
           throw new Exception2("Some message" + e.getMessage(), e);
       }

       String val = obj.doSomething();
       return val;
    }
}
```

This way, you will get the right mock on every run.

Comment: Wow, this is really smart and it works! Thank you very much!